# Check the vbTab count of in string

Tags: vba, ssrs-2008, contains

How to find the vbtab count in string because when the tab count is 3 it should move to next line

```
 Dim msg As String
       msg = "message 1" & vbTab & " Message 2 " & vbTab & "Message 3" & vbTab

Message 1         Message 2          Message 3
Message 4         Message 5          Message 6
```

it will dynamically append to the string, how can we find the vbTab Count is 3 in-order to append the newline &  vbcrlf  &

Comment: Try `Len(msg) - Len(Replace(msg,vbTab,""))` to find number of vbTabs in the variable msg.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
Dim vals() As String = msg.Split(vbTab)

 vals.Length = 3 -- you can get the count fo vbtab

 If vals.Length = 3 then
    msg= msg & vbcrlf 
 End If
```